# Decrypt AES with Secret Key and IV From Node to Golang Panic

Tags: node.js, go, encryption, aes

I have following code in node.js using crypto-js to encrypt password using AES with Secret Key and IV.

```
const crypto = require('crypto-js');

const cryptKey = 'b676eac8cf70442385dfd4bcfaa61b52';

const createRandomIv = function () {
    const keySize = 192 / 32;
    const ivSize = 128 / 32;
    const evp = crypto.algo.EvpKDF.create({ keySize: keySize + ivSize, hasher: crypto.algo.SHA1 }).compute(cryptKey);
    const iv = crypto.lib.WordArray.create(evp.words.slice(keySize), ivSize * 4);
    return iv.toString();
};

const encryptPassword = function (password) {
    const iv = createRandomIv();
    const hash = crypto.AES.encrypt(
        password,
        cryptKey, {
            iv,
            mode: crypto.mode.CTR
        }
    );
    const base64 = crypto.enc.Base64.parse(hash.toString());
    const eHex = base64.toString(crypto.enc.Hex);

    return `${iv}:${eHex}`;
};

const decryptPassword = function (encryptedPwd) {
    const split = encryptedPwd.split(':');
    if (split.length < 2) return '';
    const reb64 = crypto.enc.Hex.parse(split[1]);
    const bytes = reb64.toString(crypto.enc.Base64);
    const hash = crypto.AES.decrypt(bytes, cryptKey, {
        iv: split[0],
        mode: crypto.mode.CTR
    });
    const plain = hash.toString(crypto.enc.Utf8);
    return plain;
};
```

And here is the encrypted password from node js.

```
const encryptedPassword = encryptPassword("Stack Overflow");
console.log(encryptedPassword);
// 2db5c01b4825b6d4dd7a7b96f04f3bb5:53616c7465645f5f691671363cda1b9d05ee6bdd637e1e99bc3b29ef2ad7ec53
```

And already tried go decrpyt it using golang as follow

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    secretKey := "b676eac8cf70442385dfd4bcfaa61b52"
    encryptedPwd := "2db5c01b4825b6d4dd7a7b96f04f3bb5:53616c7465645f5f691671363cda1b9d05ee6bdd637e1e99bc3b29ef2ad7ec53"
    split := strings.Split(encryptedPwd, ":")

    c, _ := aes.NewCipher([]byte(secretKey))
    cfbdec := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(c, []byte(split[0]))
    plaintext := make([]byte, len(split[1]))
    cfbdec.CryptBlocks(plaintext, []byte(split[1]))
    fmt.Println(plaintext)
}
```

But it panics as follow.

> panic: cipher.NewCBCDecrypter: IV length must equal block size
> goroutine 1 [running]:
> crypto/cipher.NewCBCDecrypter({0x10c4ee8, 0xc000066060}, {0xc00001e040, 0x1, 0x20})

**Updated 1**

I updated the code to decrypted without using iv, but the result is not human readable.

```
split := strings.Split(encryptedPwd, ":")
ciphertext, _ := hex.DecodeString(split[1])
c, _ := aes.NewCipher([]byte(secretKey))
plaintext := make([]byte, len(ciphertext))
c.Decrypt(plaintext, []byte(ciphertext))
fmt.Println(string(plaintext))
```

> |A/��c�*Z�S/�x

What's wrong with the decryption in my golang code, can anybody please help me? I already use the same key and iv by splitting it from the encrypted password.

Comment: If you log in `encryptPassword()` the two values, `iv` and `hash.iv.toString()`, you will see that they are different, i.e. the IV elaborately determined with `createRandomIv()` is ignored during encryption.

Comment: @Topaco what do you mean, the iv is in the encrypted password on the first segment before colon, and I already use the same key and iv, how to fix it then?

Comment: I recommend you to decrypt the ciphertext with CryptoJS first. Then you will notice that the IV created with `createRandomIv()` is not needed for decryption.

Comment: @Topaco i updated the question with decrypted function on nodejs that uses the iv

Comment: Encrypt a plaintext with `encryptPassword()` and decrypt the ciphertext with `decryptPassword()`. If you comment out the line `iv: split[0],` in `decryptPassword()`, decryption still works, i.e. the IV (`split[0]`) is not needed and is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Topaco yes the decryptPassword on nodejs works without the iv, I updated my question, I tried to do the same in go, ignoring using the iv, but the result is not human readable, am i missing something, thank you btw

Comment: You pass the key as string, so it will be interpreted as passphrase. Therefore CryptoJS derives key and IV with the KDF `EVP_BytesToKey()` using a random salt. You can find an implementation for Go [here](https://github.com/walkert/go-evp). But beware, this key derivation is deprecated and insecure! The more secure alternative is to pass the key as `WordArray`, then it will be interpreted as key and used directly. In this case a random IV must be generated explicitly (and concatenated with the ciphertext for decryption).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CryptoJS code, the second parameter in `crypto.AES.encrypt()` is passed as a string, so it is interpreted as passphrase.

Therefore, during encryption, an eight bytes salt is first created and from this, along with the passphrase, key and IV are derived using the KDF `EVP_BytesToKey()`.

The IV derived with `createRandomIv()` and explicitly passed in `crypto.AES.encrypt()` is ignored!

`hash.ToString(`) returns the result in OpenSSL format consisting of the prefix *Salted__* followed by the salt and by the actual ciphertext, all Base64 encoded. `eHex` contains the same data, but hex instead of Base64 encoded.

CryptoJS does not automatically disable padding for stream cipher modes like CTR, so the data is padded with PKCS#7, although this would not be necessary for CTR.

---

In the Go code, the IV that is not required must first be removed. From the remaining data, salt and ciphertext are determined.

From salt and passphrase, key and IV can be retrieved with [`evp.BytesToKeyAES256CBCMD5()`](https://github.com/walkert/go-evp).

With key and IV the decryption with AES-CTR can be performed.

Finally, the PKCS#7 padding must be removed.

The following Go code implements these steps. The input data was generated with the NodeJS code:

```golang
import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/walkert/go-evp"
)

func main() {

    // Determine salt and actual ciphertext
    encryptedPwd := "2db5c01b4825b6d4dd7a7b96f04f3bb5:53616c7465645f5f66cbd1d539b6e51d45efded11e2211fa5e02278855dc86145d4e4891b0e25df9df96fb97a10a9f444f4519f2da4c69c430c5cbf3e9803a1f"
    split := strings.Split(encryptedPwd, ":")
    saltCiphertext, _ := hex.DecodeString(split[1])
    salt := saltCiphertext[8:16]
    ciphertext := saltCiphertext[16:]

    // Get key and IV
    key, iv := evp.BytesToKeyAES256CBCMD5([]byte(salt), []byte("b676eac8cf70442385dfd4bcfaa61b52"))

    // Decrypt
    block, _ := aes.NewCipher(key)
    plaintext := make([]byte, len(ciphertext))
    stream := cipher.NewCTR(block, iv)
    stream.XORKeyStream(plaintext, ciphertext)

    // Unpad
    unpaddedPlaintext := PKCS7Unpad(plaintext)

    fmt.Println("Decrypted data: ", string(unpaddedPlaintext)) // Decrypted data:  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
}

func PKCS7Unpad(src []byte) []byte {
    length := len(src)
    unpadding := int(src[length-1])
    return src[:(length - unpadding)]
}
```

---

Regarding security:
The derivation of key and IV performed by CryptoJS with `EVP_BytesToKey()` is considered insecure today.
The more secure alternative would be to pass the 2nd parameter as `WordArray`, so that it is interpreted as key and used directly.
For each encryption a random IV has to be generated.
Optionally, a reliable key derivation (e.g. PBKDF2) can be used in conjunction with a salt randomly generated for each encryption.
IV and salt (both not secret) are to be concatenated with the ciphertext.
It is better to use GCM instead of CTR as cipher, so that the authenticity of the ciphertext can be verified.